# cat filename | grep -i doesn't work on .sh script

Tags: bash, shell

I need to read a log file and check if there is a certain string inside that file.

I'm actually trying to run the following command on bash and it seems to work:

```
cat $f | grep -m1 'Input file for table '"$current_table"' NOT FOUND'
```

Where:

- `$f` = log file;
- `$current_table` = variable to concatenate inside the string that i'm looking for.

The point is that I have to put this code inside a `.sh` script like below:

```
if [ "$(cat $f | grep -m1 'Input file for table '"$current_table"' NOT FOUND')" != "" ]; then
```

It doesn't work.

I've tried then to run the following code in bash and it works again, where the syntax is exactly the same:

```
echo  "$(cat $f | grep -m1 'Input file for table '"$current_table"' NOT FOUND')"
```

Could anyone explain where I'm wrong? Have you any suggestions?

Comment: As a sidenote, `grep pattern file` is preferable to `cat file | grep pattern`

Comment: Try to use a separate step for building the string to search for. You can debug it more easily. Then pass it to grep.

Comment: i've tried to separate the steps but the problem still remains

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
# redirected to /dev/null to avoid output
if grep -m1 "Input file for table $current_table NOT FOUND" "$f" >/dev/null
then
    echo 'found'
else
    echo 'not found'
fi
```

You don't need `cat` with filter programs like `grep` (and `tail`, and `sed`, and etc.).

You don't need the `test` command here (also known as `[`), `if` will test for success of a command, in this case `grep`.

This assumes that `f` and `current_table` are set, I've also simplified your quoting.  Make sure you quote filenames (`"$f"`) in case they contain whitespace.

Comment: i have one more question. I would like to avoid to print grep result, how can i do that?

Comment: @M.Orlandi : `-q` should be used as it is shown in my answer

Comment: @M.Orlandi: I added a redirection to `/dev/null`, the `-q` option is not available in all implementations of `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that `current_table` variable is not defined in the script.

In the script, you should make sure that both `f` and `current_table` variables are defined and have a value assigned.

Give a try to this:

```
if [ -z "${current_table}" -o -z "${f}" ] ; then
  printf "one or both variables has no value\n"
  printf "current_table=%s\nf=%s\n" "${current_table}" "${f}"
  exit 1
fi
grep -q "Input file for table ${current_table} NOT FOUND" "${f}"
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then 
  printf "the line below was not found in the %s file.\n" "${f}"
  printf "Input file for table %s NOT FOUND\n" "${current_table}"
fi
```

The `cat` command is not needed because `grep` can search into a file directly.
Prefer the use of `printf`

Answer (score 0):

It is usually better to provide a minimal working example when asking a question, this helps people reproduce your issue.

You are likely having issues with the `"` in the log/pattern.

Here's a working sample of what you're trying to do. I've added `-n` to `grep` so you can see which line matches:

```
/t/tmp.mCbnzfsCnb> cat logfile 
line 1
Input file for table Users NOT FOUND
line 3
Input file for table "Users" NOT FOUND
line 5
```

.

```
/t/tmp.mCbnzfsCnb> cat grep-example.sh 
#!/bin/bash
set -exuo pipefail

f=logfile
current_table=Users
if [ "$(cat $f | grep -n -m1 'Input file for table '"$current_table"' NOT FOUND')" != "" ]; then
    echo "OK - no quotes"
fi

if [ "$(cat $f | grep -n -m1 'Input file for table "'$current_table'" NOT FOUND')" != "" ]; then
    echo "OK - quotes in the log"
fi

# Alternative syntax (no cat, no test)

if grep -n -m1 'Input file for table '"$current_table"' NOT FOUND' "$f"; then
    echo "OK - alternative no quotes"
fi

if grep -n -m1 'Input file for table "'$current_table'" NOT FOUND' "$f"; then
    echo "OK - alternative no quotes"
fi
```

.

```
/t/tmp.mCbnzfsCnb> ./grep-example.sh 
+ f=logfile
+ current_table=Users
++ cat logfile
++ grep -n -m1 'Input file for table Users NOT FOUND'
+ '[' '2:Input file for table Users NOT FOUND' '!=' '' ']'
+ echo 'OK - no quotes'
OK - no quotes
++ cat logfile
++ grep -n -m1 'Input file for table "Users" NOT FOUND'
+ '[' '4:Input file for table "Users" NOT FOUND' '!=' '' ']'
+ echo 'OK - quotes in the log'
OK - quotes in the log
+ grep -n -m1 'Input file for table Users NOT FOUND' logfile
2:Input file for table Users NOT FOUND
+ echo 'OK - alternative no quotes'
OK - alternative no quotes
+ grep -n -m1 'Input file for table "Users" NOT FOUND' logfile
4:Input file for table "Users" NOT FOUND
+ echo 'OK - alternative no quotes'
OK - alternative no quotes
```

Note that the difference between the two options is very subtle: `"'` vs `'"`

Also note that you can use `set -x` when troubleshooting to see step by step what is being executed.